# when using ES update_by_query, how to determine if all documents are correctly updated

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

http://localhost:9200/user/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed

```json
{
    "script": {
        "source": "ctx._source.age = params.age",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
            "age": 10
        }
    },
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "age": {
                "value": 20,
                "boost": 1.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

response:

```json
{
    "took": 28,
    "timed_out": false,
    "total": 1,
    "updated": 1,
    "deleted": 0,
    "batches": 1,
    "version_conflicts": 0,
    "noops": 0,
    "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
    },
    "throttled_millis": 0,
    "requests_per_second": -1.0,
    "throttled_until_millis": 0,
    "failures": []
}
```

- total:
  The number of documents that were successfully processed.
- updated:
  The number of documents that were successfully updated.

I'm not sure what the really mean of **total** property is. If it is the count of the query, I could check whether **total** is equal to **updated**.

//solution one

```java
if (response.getTotal() == response.getUpdated()) {
            //all updated
        } else {
            //some documents failed, retry latter
        }
```

//solution two

```java
if (response.getVersionConflicts() == 0 && CollectionUtils.isEmpty(response.getFailures())) {
            //all updated
        } else {
            //some documents failed, retry latter
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

### edit:

If you didn't specify the `wait_for_completion=false` in the `_update_by_query` request header you can find the `task_id` with the following API call:

```
GET .tasks/_search?size=1000
```

---

When you run the `_update_by_query` API Elasticsearch will create a `task_id`. If you save that task_id you can check the status with the following command:

```
GET /_tasks/r1A2WoRbTwKZ516z6NEs5A:36619
```

If you didn't save the `task_id` you can check with `_tasks` API and find your task_id if the update by query is still run.

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_tasks?detailed=true&actions=*byquery&pretty"
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#docs-update-by-query-fetch-tasks

### Use `wait_for_completion=false` the get the task_id as output.

**Here is an example:**

```
PUT test
POST test/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed&wait_for_completion=false
#response:
{
  "task": "dwXMZTfZQYuGH6FLEIxcZQ:365044451"
}

GET _tasks/dwXMZTfZQYuGH6FLEIxcZQ:365044451
#response
{
  "completed": true,
  "task": {
    "node": "dwXMZTfZQYuGH6FLEIxcZQ",
    "id": 365044451,
    "type": "transport",
    "action": "indices:data/write/update/byquery",
    "status": {
      "total": 21,
      "updated": 21,
      "created": 0,
      "deleted": 0,
      "batches": 1,
      "version_conflicts": 0,
      "noops": 0,
      "retries": {
        "bulk": 0,
        "search": 0
      },
      "throttled_millis": 0,
      "requests_per_second": -1,
      "throttled_until_millis": 0
    },
    "description": "update-by-query [test]",
    "start_time_in_millis": 1689251128726,
    "running_time_in_nanos": 6638281,
    "cancellable": true,
    "cancelled": false,
    "headers": {
      "trace.id": "1697d4a40bdfadc1494a10adcb994d95"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "took": 6,
    "timed_out": false,
    "total": 21,
    "updated": 21,
    "created": 0,
    "deleted": 0,
    "batches": 1,
    "version_conflicts": 0,
    "noops": 0,
    "retries": {
      "bulk": 0,
      "search": 0
    },
    "throttled": "0s",
    "throttled_millis": 0,
    "requests_per_second": -1,
    "throttled_until": "0s",
    "throttled_until_millis": 0,
    "failures": []
  }
}
```

1. `completed` shows if the `_update_by_query` is completed or not.
2. The `tasks.status.total` shows the **total document count**.
3. The `tasks.status.updated` shows the **updated document count**.

> Note: If the `slice` enable you can't see the `count` until the
> process is completed. Fetching the status of the task for the request
> with slices only contains the status of completed slices.

Comment: thanks, but I have passed *true* to wait_for_completion when calling update_by_query.   I'd like to get the result *synchronously* of the update operation.

Comment: answer updated : If you didn't specify the wait_for_completion=false in the _update_by_query request header you can find the task_id with the following API call:

`GET .tasks/_search?size=1000`